# Embedding HTML Help in a QT application

Tags: qt

I write an application, with Qt and it has a pretty big help system, which is including images, tables, links, etc... This help system is stored on a disk in a specific location as simple HTML files, together with the images and using a QWebkit control it's loaded in the application on request, and the user can browse it, etc...

Now, I would like to move away from my "in-house, file based" help solution, meaning: I want a help system which still will use my HTML files, but without the need to ship 100 files to the user, only 1 or 2.

I am aware of Qt's help system ( http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qthelp-framework.html ) but I am wondering if there are any other solutions providing the same or similar functionality.

What I am looking for:

1. take all the HTML files and create one of them, including images
2. reader possibly embeddable in application, but separate application is good too.
3. multiplatform
4. support for context sensitive help (ie: "Click on what's this", help shows relevant page)

Comment: One possible solution might be just zipping those files into one archive and then using some library (e.g. [QuaZIP](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/)) to read from that file. Not sure if links work, but maybe you can get that working, too (don't know too much about QtWebKit)

Answer (score 0):

For huge help docs the best way is to use [Qt Help Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthelp-framework.html). For example QAssistant is done in this way.

It mainly consists of several html like files and index files. Then you "compile" them to get a binary(and compressed) version. You can split help in sections and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I am using QWebView to display HTML help files. You get a widget and can integrate it in your application.

Qt have a good easy example here:  http://qt-project.org/wiki/Open_Web_Page_in_QWebView

Since it is a widget, you can greate a stand-alone or integrated look and it it very flexible.